# What is the meaning of '...' and '--' when encountered in a dialogue?

Tags: writing-style

While reading novels I come across'...' and '--'. (Three dots or a long dash). I was assuming it means a long pause but I am confused of alternate usages.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Look up _ellipsis_, and "m dash".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, definitions: The '...' is called an ellipses. The long dash '--' is called an em dash. The em dash is an old printer's term meaning a dash that is the width of the uppercase 'M' letter. The em dash--sometimes written 'em-dash'--is the widest letter in the type case on the upper shelf of the typesetter's composition bench. A hyphen '-', by the way, is called an en dash, the width of the captial 'N' letter.

**An ellipsis** generally indicates a continuation of a thought awaits or loosely separating a follow-on thought. For example...

- "Her argument started me thinking..."  (Explanation of what the speaker was thinking will be illustrated later on--or not).
- "Her argument started me thinking... and I always get hungry when I am thinking."

Famously, "The Dean of Three-Dot Journalism," Columnist Herb Caen of the San Francisco Chronicle would link several run-on thoughts--with ellipses--between periods in his columns because one thought would run on to several others.

**The em dash** is used to insert usually relevant--but distinct--info into a sentence. Usually, the sentence will mean exactly the same if the phrase is removed.

For example uses, consider this reply. I awkwardly peppered it with hyphens, ellipses and em dashes.